# NativeScript TextView :textTransform can't update

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I`m using NativeScript with Vue.js. I have some text in TextView and I'm trying to change that text from "none" to "uppercase" by using textTransform property. 
Here is my sample code and [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=H0kr0T) is from the ns playground

```html
<template>
    <Page class="page">
        <ActionBar title="Home" class="action-bar" />
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout>
                <TextView editable="false" :fontSize="textFontSize"
                    :textTransform="upperCaseText">
                    <FormattedString>
                        <Span text="This is a text view that uses attributed text. You can use text attributes such as " />
                    </FormattedString>
                </TextView>
                <Button text="Make uppercase" @tap="toUpperCase" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </Page>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                upperCaseText: "none",
                textFontSize: 20
            };
        },
        methods: {
            toUpperCase() {
                this.upperCaseText = "uppercase";
                this.textFontSize = 67;
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

When I click the ***Make uppercase*** button, property ***upperCaseText*** is changed from *"none"* to *"uppercase"*, but that change is not registered by **TextView** and the presented text is unchanged.

I'd tried to change the ***upperCaseText*** property from ns "dom", tried somehow to trigger event on **TextView** and to "tell" that something had changed, but without success.

Interesting here is that when i try to change the *fontSize* of the text. There is no problem, *fontSize* is visibly changed, but *textTransform* is not.

Why this happend? Why there isn't problem with *fontSize*, but with *textTransform* doesn't work? And how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Due to limitations on Android, updating text transform property will not have any effect on text that's already set on TextField / TextView. More info can be found in the related [Github issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/4186).

> **TextField & TextView (Android)**
>
> Setting text-transform property on these controls will not change the
> text inside them. In case you want to transform the text you should do
> it before setting it to text property.

I'm not sure why you have made the TextView read only (editable="false"), if you do not want a editable TextView then you could simply use a Label which should support updating text transform dynamically.

Comment: thanks for the fast response. But I can’t use Label for some other reasons. Will read for this issue from link you post. Still hope to find way to make it work.

Comment: Resetting text property after changing text-transform might work Or you may create a new TextView, remove the old one.